# C#: tail like program for text file

Tags: c#, logging, filesystems, stream

I have a log file that continually logs short lines. I need to develop a service that reacts (or polls, or listens to) to new lines added to that file, a sort of unix' tail program, so that my service is always up to date reguarding the file.

I don't think that opening a read stream and keeping it opened is a good idea. Maybe I should use the FileSystemWatcher class.

Long story short, I need to parse in real time every new line added to this file.

Any idea help or indication is really appreciated.

**EDIT**

As I've been not very clear. I do not need any program, I am *writing* a program. For reading (then processing) every new line added to the file. I mean that what I'm looking for is a methodology (or: how to implement this?) for continually *tailing* a file that keeps on been written.

I have to develop a Windows service that "listens" to this file and does operations on every new line.

So, if in a given moment the file is:

```
12.31.07 - jdoe [log on] 347
12.32.08 - ssmith [log on] 479
12.32.08 - mpeterson [log off] 532
12.32.09 - apacino [log on] 123
```

in the very moment that the line

```
12.32.11 - pchorr [log on] 127
```

is added to the log file by the logging program (that I have not access to), I need my Windows service to "react" to the line addiction, intercept the new line (`12.32.11 - pchorr [log on] 127`) and process it. And so on.

Now, I don't know how to do this. I should poll the file every n seconds, store the last read line in memory and process only the newly added lines. The problem with this is that is very slow, plus I'd be reading a very large file every time.

Or maybe I could use `FileSystemWatcher`, but I haven't found any example of using it for similar purposes.

So, what would you suggest to get the work done? Thanks.

Comment: I think he wants to do some sort of processing on the lines that are added to the log file not simply display them like tail does and he would like to know the best way to monitor the log and read in the lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend using `FileSystemWatcher` to be notified of changes to the file or files you're concerned about.  From there, I would cache information such as the size of the file between events and add some logic to only respond to full lines, etc.  You can use the `Seek()` method of the `FileStream` class to jump to a particular point in the file and read only from there.  Given these features, it shouldn't be too hard to hand-roll this functionality if that's what you need.

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution would be use , sample code provided in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7568/Tail-NET article. It is just one function copy/paste into your code.

Comment: If you are polling, this is simplest. If you are not polling, then FileSystemWatcher would be better.

Answer (score 5):

It is important to note that Microsoft (since vista/svr08) no longer updates file metadata when a file is updated (such as a log file being updated by a service).

For example, the metadata for a file such as modified date, **will not be updated** until the file is **closed** by the service/program which is updating the log file.

Therefore **FileSystemWatcher** will NOT catch log file updates as you might expect.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained whether you need a tail-like program for Windows i.e.  http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/ or if you want a windows version of tail (use cygwin) or if you're looking for some sort of log monitoring API....