# StreamReader or Other method? to do what i want

Tags: c#

I am working with a program the reads data from a file and plots it to a graph in real time. My stream is coming from a microcontroller output and I am building an interface to display the data. I am using stream reader in my routine, but I have a problem.

What I want to do is to get one line, plot it, and the get the next line inside a method. Can you please direct me as to what to use to do this. I am new to C# and I think stream reader is the best way to do this. I just need a way of being able to read new points as they come.

Thanks.

```
private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if ( curve == null ) return;

    IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;

    if (list == null) return;

    double time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;
    try
    {
        //PROBLEM (NEED TO READ ONE LINE THIS TIME AND THE NEXT LINE IN THE NEXT CALL
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt");
        String line;     
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        double value = double.Parse(line);
        list.Add(time, value);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }

    //graphing code
}
```

Comment: Is the file being written to while you read the points or is it assumed to be complete?

Comment: I think the file is being written and he needs to plot it when new information arrives.

Comment: I think you need something like the tail tool from Unix/Linux. Maybe this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197226/c-tail-like-program-for-text-file helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to cache your reader and refactor your code a little bit.

Basically if you want to read a line at each tick, you will need to move your reader out of your method and make it a field. Now when the tick occurs it will grab the same reader instance it used before. This means that it is in the same spot of the file you read last time. All you need to do is call ReadLine() to get the next line.

The way you currently have it setup, you are opening the file every single tick and only reading the first line. Just an FYI, when ReadLine returns null, you have reached the end of the file.

The code below is just a mockup of how it could be setup and hopefully give you some ideas on how it could work.

```
    StreamReader _reader;

    public void Init()
    {
        _reader = new StreamReader("FileName.txt");
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (curve == null)
            return;

        IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;

        if (list == null)
            return;

        double time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;
        try
        {
            string line = _reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                return;
            }
            double value = double.Parse(line);
            list.Add(time, value);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //Do Something
        }

    }
```

Comment: The file can't be updated while it's open for reading this way.

Comment: Yes, the file is being written to while I am reading. I have not considered that right now, but I suspected that there would be a problem.

Comment: Unmesh is correct. Since you cannot use the reader in the a using statement, you will definitely need to remember to call Dispose() once you are done or before you reuse it.

Comment: No problem. Only dispose of the reader once you are completely done with it i.e. when you are ready to stop reading from the file. This will close the stream and free up any resources it had.