# FileSystemWatcher not firing upon text file change and how to get appended lines into panel

Tags: filesystemwatcher

I'm after some help or guidance if possible.

I'm trying to monitor a text file in real time and copy the appended text into panel within windows forms.

The text file is being updated via an exe file so it might be few lines appended in quick sessions or nothing for few minutes.

I have tried FileSystemWatcher but it does not seem to work which I cannot understand and also I'm very new to this event handlers etc and still learning in progress :(

```
 private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
 public async void StandardOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {

        if (outLine.Data != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outLine.Data))  //checks if line coming from CMD is blank or empty
        {              

                // check if cmd output was redirected into a log file
                if (outLine.Data.Contains(">>"))
                {

                    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        //get log path and name
                        string[] commandLine = outLine.Data.Split('>');
                        this.logFileFullPath = commandLine[3];
                        this.logFileFullPath = this.logFileFullPath.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
                        string[] split = logFileFullPath.Split('\\');
                        this.logFileName = split[6];

                        this.path = split[0] + "\\" + split[1] + "\\" + split[2] + "\\" + split[3] + "\\" + split[4] + "\\" + split[5];

                        //// Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.                    
                        watcher.Path = this.path + "\\";
                        watcher.Filter = this.logFileName;
                        //watch for changes to a a log file 

                        watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.CreationTime);
                        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);



                        // Begin watching.
                        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    }));

                }
        }

   // Define the event handlers.
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Im here");// not showing

        //how to copy appended lines into panel?? 
    }
```

The message box in OnChanged method is not coming up. I have manually amended the file or delete it and create it but the event is not being fired.

I believe this might be related to file being used by another process which in this case is an exe file updating it when necessary. Also, I think, the risk is that I might get only partial text if exe updates the log at the same time as I read the appended lines.

Is there a better way to monitor the text file updates and copy the content onto the panel within GUI application??

UPDATE:
I have moved the code into click event or initial method and it makes no difference. Message box is not appearing

```
  public BatchRun()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        watcher.Path = "C:\\Test\\Projects\\99999\\Logs";
        watcher.Filter = "*.log";
        watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.CreationTime);
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only begin watching the file in the call to `StandardOutputHandler`.

If this method is only called after writing to the file, then the watcher won't notice any changes to the file.

You probably want to have all the code in your `MethodInvoker` action somewhere it is called when the application starts (or at least when it needs to monitor the file).

Then in your `OnChanged` method you may have to invoke `MessageBox.Show()` on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It make sense. However, I cannot start monitoring when application starts because I will not have all the details at the time i.e. file name and path hence the reason it was put in that method. but Let me try and find a way to get this info earlier.

Comment: W I have updated my question with newer version of the code and it should start listening as soon as application starts but its just not happening. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm starting to believe that the issues is with log file being used by another process and therefore nothing has been saved hence nothing is being captured by the watcher. I wrote a small application and copied all the code and it did fire until I have saved the changes to file.

Comment: I did some more digging and I was right. It only comes up once exe has stopped using it. Can someone suggest how do I monitor a file used by another process and copy the content onto a panel?

Comment: If the application that writes to the log file has written something, can you actually see the last lines in Notepad, or does the application have to close first?

If you don't see it in Notepad before the application is stopped, then it hasn't been committed to disk yet, and then the FileSystemWatcher won't trigger either.

You can also try a tool such as https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/ to see if the new log entries can be monitored at all.

Also check out the answers to a somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197226/c-tail-like-program-for-text-file

Comment: If I open the file with notepad while the application is still running, I can see what has been appended so i guess changes have been committed but I will do more test to confirm for definite.

Comment: yeah i can see changes applied and the baretail shows me the content is real time so i guess there must be a way around my problem.